# Кто может экранировать URL?

Tags: node.js, express

делаю приложение на `angular`, есть ссылки с якорями вида `/#link`, но при обращении:

```
https://site/#link
```

адрес преобразуется в

```
https:/site/#!#link
```

кто может экранировать и где поправить для желаемого эффекта

делаю на NodeJS + ExpressJS + cloud9

Comment: как вы это проверяете?

Comment: захожу на свой сайт, добавляю к корню якорь, и получаю его деформацию, в результате роутинг в ангуляре на отрабатывает

Comment: а происходят ли запросы к серверу после добавления якоря?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, нет, запросов к серверу не отправляется

Comment: понимаете, что это значит?

Comment: кто то на клиенте гадит, но у меня только angular подключен

Answer (score 1):

оказалось проблема в версии ангуляра, откатил до `1.5.10` и рецепт заработал